# Haversine Formula in Angular forEach()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, coordinates, haversine

Im having trouble getting the Haversine formula for coordinate distance to work inside an angular `forEach` method. Does anybody know anything about this or why my code won't work.

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.ASiteLocs = [{
    "name": "IL5077 BRUSSELS",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.58543899999999,38.955472,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5076 KAMPSVILLE",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.661923,39.29403,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5146 CARROLLTON",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.39965700000001,39.309142,0"
    }
  }]; //there are more locations, but there are too many put on here.
  $scope.SSiteLocs = [Same as above, different locations.];
  $scope.SiteLocs = $scope.SSiteLocs.concat($scope.ASiteLocs);
  repoSortOrder = "site.name";
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);

  function GetLocation(location) {
    $scope.myLat = location.coords.latitude;
    $scope.myLon = location.coords.longitude;
  }

  angular.forEach($scope.SSiteLocs, function(object) {
    object.carrier = 'Sprint';
  });
  angular.forEach($scope.ASiteLocs, function(object) {
    object.carrier = 'AT&T';
  });

  angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(location) {
    var clength = location.Point.coordinates.length;
    if (location.Point.coordinates.substring(clength - 2, clength) === ",0") {
      location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.substring(0, clength - 2).split(",");
      Lat = location.Point.coordinates[0];
      Lon = location.Point.coordinates[1];
      $scope.locLat = Lat;
      $scope.locLon = Lon;
      Com = ",";
      location.Point.coordinates = Lon.concat(Com, Lat);
    }
  });

    function getCoordDistance() {
        Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
          return this * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        var R = 3959; // Radius in miles 
        //has a problem with the .toRad() method below.
        var x1 = $scope.myLat - $scope.Lat;
        var dLat = x1.toRad();
        var x2 = $scope.myLon - $scope.Lon;
        var dLon = x2.toRad();
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
          Math.cos($scope.Lat.toRad()) * Math.cos($scope.myLat.toRad()) *
          Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        $scope.d = R * c;

      }
    
    angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(object) {
    getCoordDistance();
    object.distance = $scope.d;
  });
});
```

Comment: I am familiar with Angular but I have 2 points. #1.Pass the two sets of coordinates as parameters in function and return d. #2.Using the modified function try it with test coordinates to see that it returns the required distance.

Comment: Passing the parameters changes nothing, but using test coordinates it does work. @davidstrachan

Comment: You should have `getCoordDistance()` in first `forEach()`. In its own loop you will only have the last `$scope.Lat` & `$scope.Lon` from first `forEach()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand that. Are you saying throw `getCoordDistance()` into its own loop?

Comment: As I stated earlier I am not familiar with Angular but with over 40 years of coding I can understand logic.`angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(location)` gets the coordinates but does not seem to use them. If you have `getCoordDistance()` in this loop it will use the coords as they obtained. email me at daviestrachan@yahoo.co.uk as you don't have enough rep to chat

Comment: Alright I will email you, but in your first comment you said you ARE familiar with angular. Just pointing that out.  @davidstrachan